# How to calculate 95% confidence interval for unbiased effect size (Hedges' g) between 3 groups for a set of variables in a dataset?

Tags: r, statistics, data-manipulation

I have received great support/help on my first question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42217598/calculating-effect-sizes-between-3-groups-for-a-set-of-variables-in-a-dataset). And I would like to further explore this topic by calculating confidence intervals around the found effect sizes.

## Data

Suppose the following dataset, where x1, x2, x3 are observations of three treatment conditions which are indicative of doses: low, mid, and high. I would like to calculate the 95% confidence interval for the unbiased effect size (Hedges' g) between the treatments for a set of variables in a dataset.

```
set.seed(1234)

df1 <- data.frame(dose = factor(
  c(rep(1,25), rep(2,35), rep(3,40)),
  levels = c(1, 2, 3),
  labels = c("low", "middle", "high")),
  x1 = rnorm(100, 0, 2),
  x2 = rnorm(100, 3, 3),
  x3 = rnorm(100, 9, 4)
)
```

## Data Wrangling

```
df1$dose <- as.character(df1$dose)     # convert dose from factor to character

selected_cols <- colnames( df1 )[2:4]  # select columns prefixed with 'x'

library("reshape2")  # load reshape2 library

df1 <- melt(data = df1, id = "dose", measure.vars=selected_cols, value.name = 'value')  # melt df1
```

## Function to calculate unbiased Cohen's d effect size (Hedges' g)

```
cohens_d <- function(x, y) {
  lx <- length(x)- 1
  ly <- length(y)- 1
  md  <- abs(mean(x) - mean(y))
  csd <- lx * var(x) + ly * var(y)
  csd <- csd/(lx + ly)
  csd <- sqrt(csd)

  cd  <- md/csd
  # Hedges'g 
  cd*(1-(3/(4*(length(x)+length(y)-9))))
}
```

## Computing

```
cohens_df1 <- with(df1, sapply( selected_cols, # loop through column names
                                function( x ) combn(unique(dose), 2 ,  # loop through pairs of dose combinations
                                function( y ) cohens_d(
                                df1[ variable %in% x & dose %in% y[1], 'value' ], 
                                df1[ variable %in% x & dose %in% y[2], 'value' ] ))))
```

## Data Wrangling 2

```
rownames(cohens_df1) <- combn( unique(df1$dose), 2 , function(y) paste(y, collapse =  ' vs. '))

df2 <- melt(cohens_df1)
df2 # Results

             Var1 Var2      value
1  low vs. middle   x1 0.38938026
2    low vs. high   x1 0.33692540
3 middle vs. high   x1 0.04375728
4  low vs. middle   x2 0.03794916
5    low vs. high   x2 0.25642133
6 middle vs. high   x2 0.21583245
7  low vs. middle   x3 0.21777740
8    low vs. high   x3 0.16839399
9 middle vs. high   x3 0.09492162
```

## Question

Now that I have the effect sizes, I would like to calculate the confidence interval around these estimates. So, how to calculate 95% confidence interval for unbiased effect size (Hedges' g) between 3 groups for a set of variables in a dataset? I found [this interesting post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140460/how-can-i-calculate-the-95-confidence-interval-of-an-effect-size-if-i-have-the) on stats.stackexchange.com but I am failing in my attempts to try to implement it on the function I already have. Ideally, I would like to obtain a generalizable function that yields the same output as in `df2`, but with two additional columns `ci.low` and `ci.high`, for the confidence intervals for each estimate of the effect sizes.

Comment: Please provide just necessary pieces relevant to the question. In your case, this is probably only the last chunk, which would, preferably, be in a format we can copy/paste into our R sessions. Also, please provide the formula you're trying to implement and list your attempts. This is arguably a good way of conveying your problem in clearest possible manner with the ultimate goal of convincing other to dig into your problem and possibly solving it.

Comment: I would think all the necessary pieces are in the post. For example, one would need a reproducible example of my data [chunk 1], then a function to calculate Cohen's D, then the computing part, which was the object of my first post, and finally a representation of the data I have now,  and which I would need help with. I understand it is a complex problem and for this reason I tried to be thorough. If however that is not helpful, I can try to change it, but I wanted to confirm with you that was the best thing to do. Thank you for your help!